# Prevent web pack from bundling react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How do I prevent webpack from bundling react?
Currently I am writing a library that causes a `You've loaded two copies of React on the page.` error after distribution. I suspect that webpack starts bundling all dependencies, including devDependencies.

Is there any way around that?

In my case it should be possible for the library to get React out of node_modules.

So what I basicly want is, instead of webpack resolving the `require('React)`, it should just leave `require('React)` untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webpack [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

```
 externals: {
        // Use external version of React
        "react": "React"
 }
```

**UPD** [Detailed docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) on the resulting code generated for `externals.`

To make webpack "leave require('React) untouched" you need the following config

```
{
  output: { libraryTarget: 'commonjs' },
  externals: { react: true }
  ...
}
```

Comment: In my understanding, that makes it dependant, that there is a global variable called "React", right?

Comment: @Moezalez It depends on `outputType` you choose. If you output type is `var` it will. There is a whole section in [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) explaining what resulting code will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

[Moelalez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4258088/moezalez), just like [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) stated, `externals` option allows you  import an existing API into applications. For context, say you want to use React from a CDN via a separate  tag and still declare it as a dependency via require("react") in your application, you would use `externals` option to specify that.